# divide uint64_t data containing N decimal digits into two uint32_t and trim the output in C

Tags: c, pointers, trim

I need to divide two parts into high 8 decimal digits , low 8 decimal digit
I will not write all the details of the code. (e.g. memory allocation etc)
focusing for N decimal digits as input with data type uint64_t* and divide into two 8 decimal digits for first 8 digits, next 8 digits (data type uint32_t), so if there are more digitis, it will be just trimmed.
(Please understand I am a newbie. so if there are wrong in the code, appreciate explanation, only criticism without explanation will not help the newbies)

The code expected to work like this:
Assumption: `uint8_t* data_64b` as input contains already N decimal digits.

e.g.1)

- `1234567803456789` as input (16 decimal digits) in `uint64_t*
  data_64bits`
- Then , the output will be `12345678`, or `03456789` based on the id.

e.g.2)

- the input data has 17 decimal digits: `98765432155555553`
- Then I assume that the last 1 digit '3' should be thrown out.
- And output will be each 8 digits either `98765432` or `15555555`
  based on id

The code:

```
// @Input: unit8_t id                       input identifier 
// @input: uint64_t* data_64bits   input parameter , assume it contains N decimal digits number
// @output: uint32_t* data_32bits  output parameter to return the divided each 8 decimal digits 
dataFrom64To32bits( uint8_t id, uint64_t* data_64bits, uint32_t* data_32bits )
{  
    uint8_t* data_64bits;    /* 64bits */

#if 0 
/* [A] My original thoughts, but I have told this is not necessary. 
because the data contains decimal digits
[Q1] really don't need this? */

    uint32_t 4BytesLSB;
    uint32_t 4BytesMSB;

    4BytesLSB = data_64bits & 0xFFFFFFFF;                 /* obtains the 4 LSB */
    4BytesMSB = (data_64bits & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32; /* obtains the 4 MSB */
#endif

#if 1
    /* [B] I have got advice like this, 
and have told that it will be enough doing like this 
for 8 decimal digits for high part, low part to divide.
[Q2] Does this really make sense? and will give the result? */
    if(id == id_highpart)
    {
        *data_32bits = ( *data_64bits / 100000000 ) % 100000000;
    }
    else if(id == id_lowpart)
    {
        *data_32bits = *data_64bits % 100000000;
    }
#endif
}
```

Dose it make sense?

A part told that is not necessary.
B part adviced for the expected result
Please look at [Q1], [Q2] in the code.

Additional,
which is the right for throwing out the rest from the certain part in the code? trim or something else? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Part [B] makes sense but note that it throws out the `9`and will give you `87654321` and `55555553` for the 17 digit number. The problem with your code is that you have two items called `data_64bits`. The first is a function parameter, the second is a local variable. You need to get rid of the local variable, or change its name.

Comment: Suppose the number is 123456789; where do which digits go an why?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: The approach with `%` and `/` is correct

Comment: @user3386109 Additional question: 1) what happens if I use part A instead of part B? and 2) when using part B, if I am not doing % , then what happens?

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user1915570 Try it with 8765432155555553 and tell me what you get.

Answer (score 0):

> Additional, which is the right for throwing out the rest from the
>   certain part in the code? trim or something else?

To discard digits after the 16th, divide by 10 until there are no more (before extracting the parts):

```
    while (*data_64bits > 9999999999999999ll) *data_64bits /= 10;
```